# Is it possible to get resource based on target type in WinRT platform

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, winrt-component

In WPF we can able to get the style based on the target type, like below:

```
control.Style = (Style)toplevelcontrol.TryFindResource(typeof(control))
```

But in WinRT I can't do that. I can only use a key to get the resource. Is it possible to get the resource based on target type? 
Please help me to resolve this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between WPF and Winrt for dealing with resources here is that you get `FindResource()` and siblings in WPF objects, while in Winrt you just have the `Resources` property.

The basic technique, where the object type is used as the key for `TargetType` styles, still works though. Here's a simple helper extension method to do what you want:

```
public static object TryFindResource(this FrameworkElement element, object key)
{
    if (element.Resources.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        return element.Resources[key];
    }

    return null;
}
```

Call just like you would in WPF:

```
control.Style = (Style)toplevelcontrol.TryFindResource(control.GetType());
```

(Note that your original example would not compile, as `control` is a variable, and you can't use `typeof` on a variable. I've fixed the bug in the above example call).

Answer (score 0):

this also works so good like below,

```
 if (element.Resources.ContainsKey(key))
            return element.Resources[key];
        else
        {
            if (element.Parent != null && element.Parent is FrameworkElement)
                return ((FrameworkElement)element.Parent).TryFindResource(key);
            else
            {
                if (Application.Current.Resources.ContainsKey(key))
                    return Application.Current.Resources[key];
            }
        }
```

if element dont have that key it search in its parent element